# Java invoke EJB from servlet

Tags: java, reflection, ejb

I have a servlet that I want to dynamically call an EJB object from it accordinally to the parameter the servlet gets.

What is the best way to invoke the EJB object and methods?

**UPDATE**:
for example, the parameter I get is the sessionBean's name , so I want to invoke it (by it's name) and then call some methods inside of it, so it will be created dynamically.

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: Do you want to call an EJB whose identity depends on the parameters given to the servlet (implying context lookup) or just modify the method called on an EJB that's always the same?

Comment: @fvu: `call an EJB whose identity depends on the parameters given to the servlet` - this is what i want, the EJB does not exist so i want to create it by name and then call some methods, thank's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via a [JNDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) lookup.

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
MyEJB ejb = (MyEJB) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/MyEJB");
```

This will retrieve the remote interface of MyEJB, just create the lookup string based on servlet parameters. If you have no clue on the methods, you should use reflection to find out.

Comment: This is only required in JSP. Servlet just requires an EJB to be injected using the `@EJB` annotation.

Comment: @Lion the name of the bean is comming in with the servlets client request .... quite funny requirements.

Comment: I sincerly hope that the servlet parameters do not contain the exact bean name! It would be okay though if you had a kind of command pattern on which you performed a switch on an incomming "command", determine a bean name from it and use that name to do a lookup.

Comment: @Mike Braun: can you explain why getting the bean name from the servlet parameter is a problam ? thank's.

Comment: Via a request parameter a user can enter every name, eg AdminBean. This lets the user execute unintended code and should always be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get this result without a whole series of `@EJB` injections is to use lookup.  Let's assume that you have figured out that you need an instance of EJB1, the lookup code will look like this:

```
private EJB1 ejb1 = null;
try {
    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
    ejb1 = (EJB1)
            ic.lookup(ejb1.class.getName());
    ejb1.method1();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Couldn’t create converter bean.",ex);
}
```

Check our server's examples for the exact syntax to be used in the creation of the InitialContext and the lookup call.